# PHPass or password_hash()?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

Which one is considered the superior standard now between the two? Is one clearly better than the other or are there pros/cons to each?

Assuming that one has access to PHP 5.5+?

Comment: SolarDesigner is the guy who wrote phpass. He also wrote [John the Ripper](http://www.openwall.com/john/) (a standard password cracking tool in the pen tester's toolkit). He stays up to date on password cracking technologies. If anyone is qualified to write a password hashing library, its SolarDesigner. I'm not sure the same can be said about the PHP developers.

Answer (score 4):

The phpass library is well written and was necessary because PHP did not offer an easy way to calculate safe password hashes. Since PHP now has built-in support (e.g. for BCrypt) with the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function, this is the most future-proof way to hash passwords.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the new Password Hashing API. I don't even knew PHPass until now. Considering the Password Hashing API is built by PHP developers and not from some external developers, the Password Hashing API has the better integration and *can* use the newest and strongest algorithm available for PHP.